# How to reinstall TypeScript

Tags: typescript, npm, tsc

I installed TypeScript a while ago using npm.
It worked, but it was out of date.
So I tried to upgrade it with npm.
Somehow I broke everything.

Is there a way to force a fresh install?

This is what I've tried:

```
Philip Smolen@DESKTOP-UOBK4AV MINGW64 ~
$ npm uninstall  typescript
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\package.json'
npm WARN Philip Smolen No description
npm WARN Philip Smolen No repository field.
npm WARN Philip Smolen No README data
npm WARN Philip Smolen No license field.

removed 1 package in 0.39s
found 0 vulnerabilities


Philip Smolen@DESKTOP-UOBK4AV MINGW64 ~
$ npm install typescript
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\package.json'
npm WARN Philip Smolen No description
npm WARN Philip Smolen No repository field.
npm WARN Philip Smolen No README data
npm WARN Philip Smolen No license field.

+ typescript@4.2.3
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1 package in 0.975s
found 0 vulnerabilities


Philip Smolen@DESKTOP-UOBK4AV MINGW64 ~
$ tsc --version
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Philip Smolen@DESKTOP-UOBK4AV MINGW64 ~
$ npm install --force typescript
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\package.json'
npm WARN Philip Smolen No description
npm WARN Philip Smolen No repository field.
npm WARN Philip Smolen No README data
npm WARN Philip Smolen No license field.

+ typescript@4.2.3
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 1.14s
found 0 vulnerabilities


Philip Smolen@DESKTOP-UOBK4AV MINGW64 ~
$ tsc --version
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Philip Smolen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}    

Philip Smolen@DESKTOP-UOBK4AV MINGW64 ~
$ npm list
C:\Users\Philip Smolen
`-- typescript@4.2.3

Philip Smolen@DESKTOP-UOBK4AV MINGW64 ~
$
```

This is the first and only time I've used npm.
I can't find any documentation on troubleshooting.

Comment: you need to install/typescript globally if you are not in a project that has a package.json npm install -g typescript or npm uninstall -g typescript

Answer (score 1):

you can list your globally installed packages that are outdated

```
npm outdated -g
```

#### update

If you want to update all global packages

```sh
npm update -g
# or
yarn global upgrade
```

If you want to update a specific global package e.g. typescript

```
npm update -g typescript
```

#### uninstall and re-install

[uninstalling packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies#uninstalling-global-packages)

```sh
npm uninstall -g typescript
# or
yarn global remove typescript
```

```sh
# For the latest stable version
npm install -g typescript
# or yarn
yarn global add typescript

# or if you want nightly builds
npm install -g typescript@next
# or yarn
yarn global add typescript@next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to upgrade all your packages (and install the new versions):

```
npm upgrade
```

Alternatively, use this to install typescript itself.

```
npm i typescript
```

Comment: I also tried "upgrade".  It's not listed in my original question because I tried so many things.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @larizzatg 's suggestion and additional trial and error, this is what finally worked for me:

```
npm install -g --force typescript
```